# Compile error with T4MVC generated code in a MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

We are developing a web application with ASP.Net 4 & MVC 3 Framework. I've installed T4MVC through NuGet and all the Views, Controllers and static content are succesfully generated as strong types.

But, when I try to compile the project, it raises an error at generated file T4MVC.cs, which is:

```
'T4MVC_ViewResultBase.FindView(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext)': 
 return type must be 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineResult' to match overridden member
 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.FindView(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext)'
```

This is the source code generated:

```
[GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
public class T4MVC_ViewResultBase : System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase,
                                                            IT4MVCActionResult 
{
  public T4MVC_ViewResultBase(string area, string controller, string action):
      base()  {
       this.InitMVCT4Result(area, controller, action);
    }

    protected override void FindView(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context){}

    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public RouteValueDictionary RouteValueDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

The error says that:

```
protected override void FindView(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) { }
```

should be:

```
protected override ViewEngineResult 
               FindView(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) { }
```

But then it raises another compiling error, as this method should return code.

If we check the base class it inherits from, *System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase*, it actually declares *FindView()* with *ViewEngineResult* return type:

```
public abstract class ViewResultBase : ActionResult
    {
        ...
        protected abstract ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context);
    }
```

Has anyone got this error? Has it something to do with MVC version, are we are using MVC 3?

Thanks a lot!
Sergi

Comment: hmm. This is tricky. Nope, nothing with the version, t4mvc works fine for my mvc3 app. Hope David Ebbo will answer this =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I see the problem, and it is a T4MVC bug. But hopefully it's easy to work around.

Do you have a controller action that is declared to return a ViewResultBase? If so, can you change the return type to be ActionResult? Or alternatively you can change the return type to be whatever the concrete type is that you're returning (e.g. is it ViewResult)?

The T4MVC bug is that it doesn't correctly override non-void methods in ActionResult types.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look and tell you.

Comment: Yes! that was it! 

I'll ask the developer why this action was returning "ViewResultBase". Changing it to "ViewResult" made the trick.

I've been looking into the T4MVC.tt template, and I found this at line 333:

`<#=method.IsPublic ? "public" : "protected" #> override void <#=method.Name #>(<#method.WriteFormalParameters(true); #>) { }`

where I could see that _void_ hardcoded. I supose that's what you meant that _ it doesn't correctly override non-void methods in ActionResult types_.

I tried to fix it checking `method.ReturnType == "Void"`, but obviously you need to return something...